# Powershell escape single quotes

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm try to write a script to go through some file but it keep remove any words after '

```
$regex = "\[([\w|\s*-]+)\]([\w|\s]+(?:\[[\w|\s]+\])?.*)\s*-\s*([\w|,|\s.]+)";
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $p -Filter *.txt|
    ForEach-Object {
        $name = $_.BaseName
        $groups = [regex]::Match($name, $regex).Captures.Groups
        write-host $groups[1] $groups[2] $groups[3]
}
```

Format for file name
**[Test] Test - Test'Test**

The out put comes as **[Test] Test - Test** it keep missing any single quotes, how do i escape this

how do it get **[Test] Test - Test'Test**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't include a single quote as a valid character in the last grouping `([\w|,|\s.]+)`. Just add a single quote there to include that:

```
$regex = "\[([\w\s*-]+)\]([\w\s]+(?:\[[\w\s]+\])?.*)\s*-\s*([\w,\s.']+)"
```